# How to change values of a column

Tags: python

I have a column ['variable name'] with values 1 and 2 in my dataset. Value 1 needs to be changed into 100 and value 2 in 0. How do I do this?

I have this simple example which should work, but I have to change it to work for my dataset as well:

```
a=[1,2]
a[0]=100
a[1]=0
print(a)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify it a little bit more? You should provide a minimal working example with the problem, not one that is working as you expected.

Comment: Is your ``dataset`` a dict?

Comment: What is your "dataset"? A pandas dataframe? Something from numpy? Or just a simple list or dictionary? Please [edit] your question and add some details and the appropriate [tag]s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column is in a pandas DataFrame, you could do this:

```
dic = {1:100, 2:0}
df['variable name'].replace(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn your column into a numpy array and then use slicing. As in:

```
a=np.array([1,2])
a[a==1]=100
a[a==2]=0
print(a)
```

which prints `[100,0]`.